# How to get the frequency spectrum of a segment of samples from a AudioInputStream?

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, fft

Is there a nice (pure Java) open source libary to get the frequence spectrum of samples taken from a [AudioInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several FFT libraries, for example [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/transform/FastFourierTransformer.html) includes a FFT.

Bear in mind, though, that *spectrum estimation* is something more complicated than simply making a Fourier transform (DFT). (It's true, though, that the most basic method, the [Periodogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodogram), amounts to computing the DFT and taking its absolute value).

Answer (score 0):

The website for FFTW, one of the most popular FFT libraries, supposedly has Java bindings. Check out the descriptions on http://www.fftw.org/download.html .